# Multi Threading C# Task Completer

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Program that need's to connect's to some amount of SSH servers.
[ if they are not busy ] , [ should change status, if doing task should change to true, if finished should change to false ].

and complete some tasks on that SSH.
i have SSH List, threads array, and Task's list.

all i need to do [ at this stage ].

-SSH => if doing task ( `IsBusy = true` ).
-SSH => if not doing task or finished ( `IsBusy = false` ). 
-if [ `IsBusy = false` ] using threads .. should take a task to comeplete it.
when the server takes task , it should be removed from the tasks list, and as will IsBusy is true.
- The task should be async !.

---

```
    public static List<string> tasks = new List<string>();
    public static List<SSH> servers = new List<SSH>();
```

in the Main.cs

```
        // Adding Poco Tasks
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        // Adding Poco Servers           
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            servers.Add(new SSH() { Name = i.ToString(), IsBusy = false });
        }
        // My Threads Array
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(async () =>
            {
                await CompleteTask(tasks[0]);
            });
            threads[i] = thread;
        }
        // Just Renaming Threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
            threads[i].Start();
        }
```

and the Task

```
    static async Task CompleteTask(string task)
    {
        while (tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current Thread is {0} ans Status is {1} Tasks id = {2} ", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive, task);
                tasks.Remove(task);
            }
        }
    }
```

the Result iam looking for

```
Current Thread is 1 ans Status is True Tasks id = 1
Current Thread is 2 ans Status is True Tasks id = 2
Current Thread is 3 ans Status is True Tasks id = 3
Current Thread is 1 ans Status is True Tasks id = 4
Current Thread is 4 ans Status is True Tasks id = 5
Current Thread is 5 ans Status is True Tasks id = 6
Current Thread is 2 ans Status is True Tasks id = 7
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. --- In your question you fail to ask a question, and fail to say how your code isn't working. I'm not going to put time and effort into helping if your question isn't there / isn't clear.

Comment: Don't mix tasks and threads.

Comment: how ? i just dont know what to do next to fix the behavior

Comment: Read about tasks and async, await. You can create list of tasks and await them with `await Task.WhenAll`, but you first have to learn about it. Google it.

Comment: Actually, no one Helped me.
I just used `Parallel.ForEach();`